Reconstruction of an operator given the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues
I am interested in operator theory, in particular if I know the sequence of eigenvalues $\{\lambda_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subset \mathbb{R}$ and eigenfunctions $f_n \subset X$ of a self-adjoint differential operator $A:X \rightarrow Y$, then can I reconstruct the operator?
For example, if I know that the eigenvalues $\lambda_n = n(n+1)$ and the corresponding eigenfunctions are the spherical harmonic functions $Y_{n,m}\in C^\infty(\mathbb{S}^2)$, then can I deduce that the corresponding operator is the spherical Laplacian?
Furthermore, given the above, if I were to alter the eigenvalue sequence to be $\lambda_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}$ then can I say anything about this new operator given the other one?

Are you familiar with the Spectral Theorem?

@user619894 In that we can decompose an operator into a weighted sum orthogonal projections, where the weights are the eigenvalues? I am familiar, but I am not sure how to find these orthogonal projections given the eigenfunctions.

@mathematurgist The orthogonal projection corresponding to an eigenvalue is exactly the projection onto the space spanned by the eigenfunctions associated with that eigenvalue. So, assuming your eigenfunctions $f_n$ are normalized, then $A = \sum_n \lambda_n |f_n \rangle \langle f_n|$. This is generally true for self-adjoint compact operators and self-adjoint unbounded operators with compact inverses, which include most differential operators on bounded domains.

Now, this doesn’t exactly tell you what the operator is in terms of other differential operators. Indeed, for an arbitrary sequence of eigenfunctions, it doesn’t have to be related to any differential operator at all. But if your sequence of eigenfunctions coincide with that of a differential operator and only eigenvalues are altered, then the new operator can be obtained from the old one via functional calculus (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_functional_calculus). In particular, for your example in the final paragraph, $A = \Delta^{-1/2}$.

@DavidGao Thank you, your comments are very helpful, it is now clear that I can represent my operator in terms of an integral kernal. Whilst the prospect about learning about the fractional spherical Laplacian is terrifying I am interested. I do have a follow up question, specifically if there is some regularity with regards to the Borel calculus? e.g. if my eigvenalues are $1/\sqrt(n(n+1))\arcsin(\sqrt(n(n+1))/(1+\sqrt(n(n+1))))$ then can the same methodology apply, or is it just for linear systems?

@mathematurgist Taking $-1/2$-th power is not linear either, so yes, there’s no restriction on what functions you can use. (They have to be Borel, but we are dealing with a countable set of eigenvalues here, so all functions are Borel.) Insofar as there is some given function $f$ that turns the eigenvalues of the old operator $T$ to the eigenvalues of the new one $S$ (and the eigenfunctions are the same), then $S = f(T)$. (All these assume $T$ is Hermitian, and is either compact or has compact inverse, but again this is generally the case for differential operators on bounded domains.)
